# OpenCV Weird Memory Corruption

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, memory-leaks, runtime-error

I set up OpenCV with Visual Studio for a project and I am getting these really weird memory errors. I have been searching extensively for a fix to this, and while there are many similar questions, they are either unanswered or not working for me.

This is one of the few OpenCV functions I'm having problems with (got it from [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)), which replicates the errors I get:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src; Mat src_gray;
int thresh = 100;
int max_thresh = 255;
RNG rng(12345);


/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /// Load source image and convert it to gray
    std::string img = "<path-to-picture>";
    src = imread(img, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    /// Convert image to gray and blur it
    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3, 3));

    /// Create Window
    char* source_window = "Source";
    namedWindow(source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow(source_window, src);

    Mat canny_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using canny
    Canny(src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh * 2, 3);
    /// Find contours
    findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    /// Draw contours
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
        drawContours(drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);


    waitKey(0);
    return(0);
}
```

**Weird thing is that findContours() works perfectly, but after that the program crashes with this error**:

```
Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT - 1)) == 0" && 0
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Here's my OpenCV setup:

- Visual Studio 2015, Debug/Release x64
- OpenCV 2.4.13 (pre-built)
- *C++ includes* points to `build\include`
- *C++ linker* points to `\build\x64\vc12\lib`
- Dependencies includes libs in the above folder.

Comment: First, press Retry and follow the call stack until you reach your own code to find out which OpenCV function failed.

Comment: @molbdnilo In my project code, I evaluated the stack trace *multiple* times and I am certain that findContours() is failing. If you want, I can add that stack trace as well.

Comment: Which one is true, then? "findContours() works perfectly" or "I am certain that findContours() is failing"?

Comment: @molbdnilo The weird part is that findContours works, but after the vectors I pass to it go out of scope, it crashes, with the stacktrace showing it crashed at vector's deallocator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using OpenCV build with vc12 compiler (Visual Studio 2013), but in your project you're using vc14 (Visual Studio 2105).

Be sure to use the prebuild libs compiled with vc14.

I'm sure OpenCV 3.1 has prebuild binaries for vc14. I don't know if OpenCV 2.4.13 has them, too (probably not). In this case you need to recompile OpenCV with vc14, or switch to OpenCV 3.1

Comment: I have never built OpenCV myself, so I was hoping for a simpler solution :(

Comment: Just download opencv 3.1 then, or use visual studio 2013 ;D

Comment: Turns out building 2.4.13 on VC14 fails *horribly*. Ended up building it on VC12, as I needed OpenMP and CUDA.